# SQL Server select based on specific condition

Tags: sql-server

I would like to exclude records which having `UserID` as NULL only if there is at least one record which has a value in it.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @MySavedSearches WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT SSM.* 
    FROM XYZTABLE SSM
    JOIN @MySavedSearches MySearches ON SSM.UniqueID = MySearches.UniqueID AND MySearches.UserID IS NOT NULL
ELSE
    SELECT SSM.* 
    FROM XYZTABLE  SSM
    JOIN @MySavedSearches MySearches ON SSM.UniqueID = MySearches.UniqueID
```

With above query I am able to get desired result, but somehow I feel it's not the correct way.

Comment: You can put it all in one query without the `AND` part of the join by using a WHERE clause. e.g. `WHERE CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @MySavedSearches WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL) THEN MySearches.UserID ELSE 1 END IS NOT NULL`. This is just saying, "if it exists, it has to not be null, if it doesn't, grab everything." To find the "correct" way of doing it, just test different methods and find out which ones execute the fastest, I guess.

Comment: your issue has resolved ?

Comment: Whatever the code I posted in question is working fine. I just want to know any other better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the count to a variable and check inside the where:

```
DECLARE @cnt int
SELECT @cnt = count(*) FROM @MySavedSearches WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL

SELECT SSM.* 
    FROM XYZTABLE SSM
    JOIN @MySavedSearches MySearches ON SSM.UniqueID = MySearches.UniqueID 
             AND ((@cnt > 0 AND MySearches.UserID IS NOT NULL) OR (@cnt = 0))
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for this solution, This is bit better compare to mine. But I am still looking for better approach